# WooCommerce - Show Final Shipping Selection on Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Maybe I've been staring at WooCommerce core files for too long, but I can't figure out how to show *only the final shipping selection* on the Checkout page. 
Here's some background:
I'm trying to streamline the process for checkout. I'd like for shipping method to be selected *only* on the Cart page. If it's a Local Pickup, then a conditional field will appear under order notes to choose their pickup location. But, when you get to your final order review on the Chekcout page, Woo lets you re-select your shipping option which throws a wrench in the works. I basically just want to echo their selection and price for shipping and not let them change the selection unless they go back to the cart page.

So I looked into woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php and this calls on the cart to pull the Shipping options like so:

```
<?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
```

This function is actually from the Cart:

```
function wc_cart_totals_shipping_html() {
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
$first    = true;

foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {
$chosen_method = isset( WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] ) ? WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods[ $i ] : '';
$product_names = array();

if ( sizeof( $packages ) > 1 ) {
  foreach ( $package['contents'] as $item_id => $values ) {
    $product_names[ $item_id ] = $values['data']->get_name() . ' &times;' . $values['quantity'];
  }
  $product_names = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_details_array', $product_names, $package );
}

wc_get_template( 'cart/cart-shipping.php', array(
  'package'                  => $package,
  'available_methods'        => $package['rates'],
  'show_package_details'     => sizeof( $packages ) > 1,
  'show_shipping_calculator' => is_cart() && $first,
  'package_details'          => implode( ', ', $product_names ),
  // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
  'package_name'             => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_package_name', sprintf( _nx( 'Shipping', 'Shipping %d', ( $i + 1 ), 'shipping packages', 'woocommerce' ), ( $i + 1 ) ), $i, $package ),
  // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
  'index'                    => $i,
  'chosen_method'            => $chosen_method,
) );

$first = false;
  }
}
```

Now, I also looked into woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php and found this:

```
/**
 * Add shipping lines to the order.
 *
 * @param WC_Order $order                   Order Instance.
 * @param array    $chosen_shipping_methods Chosen shipping methods.
 * @param array    $packages                Packages.
 */
public function create_order_shipping_lines( &$order, $chosen_shipping_methods, $packages ) {
    foreach ( $packages as $package_key => $package ) {
        if ( isset( $chosen_shipping_methods[ $package_key ], $package['rates'][ $chosen_shipping_methods[ $package_key ] ] ) ) {
            $shipping_rate            = $package['rates'][ $chosen_shipping_methods[ $package_key ] ];
            $item                     = new WC_Order_Item_Shipping();
            $item->legacy_package_key = $package_key; // @deprecated For legacy actions.
            $item->set_props(
                array(
                    'method_title' => $shipping_rate->label,
                    'method_id'    => $shipping_rate->method_id,
                    'instance_id'  => $shipping_rate->instance_id,
                    'total'        => wc_format_decimal( $shipping_rate->cost ),
                    'taxes'        => array(
                        'total' => $shipping_rate->taxes,
                    ),
                )
            );
            foreach ( $shipping_rate->get_meta_data() as $key => $value ) {
                $item->add_meta_data( $key, $value, true );
            }
            /**
             * Action hook to adjust item before save.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_shipping_item', $item, $package_key, $package, $order );
            // Add item to order and save.
            $order->add_item( $item );
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like the action hook at the end of the last code will get me there, but I can't figure out which function to mess with or what I can use *to* replace it.

Comment: The changes to be maid are in `cart/cart-shipping.php` templates…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm not looking to change the core template, though. I'm wanting to hook into the output on the checkout page only. I prefer to use hooks, as updating the plugin will overwrite all template changes.

Comment: This is a template maid to be overridden via the theme, so not a core file… See this official documentation: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/